# Magento 2 Translations not working on plugins

Tags: magento2, plugin, translate

I have a translation file in

app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv

"sample_trans","Sample Trans"

my problem is when i try to call it in a plugin via __('sample_trans'). it doesnt work and it just return 'sample_trans'. its weird that this is working when you call __('sample_trans') in a controller.

does anyone has an idea why theme level translations are not working on plugins?

Comment: Same issue here, found the solution ?